# How to force label to left side of form field

Tags: html, css, forms

I have embedded an email sign-up form on my site and the CSS is conflicting with it. How do I get the email form label to force to the left or top of form field? It's sitting on right of field now.

HTML:

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >
<input type="text" id="rm_email" name="rm_email" />
Email:<br>
<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="12565">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >
Email: <input type="text" id="rm_email" name="rm_email" />
<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="12565">
```

You could also your label so you can apply CSS to it directly...

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >
<label for="rm_email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="rm_email" name="rm_email" />
<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="12565">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for inline-style:

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >
  Email:
<input type="text" id="rm_email" name="rm_email" />

<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="12565">
```

and this for one above each other

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" >
 Email:<br>
<input type="text" id="rm_email" name="rm_email" />

<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="12565">
```